# Hiding "Enter PIN" screen from Windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

With Windows mobile 6.1, how do you remove/hide the "Enter PIN" screen?

I need to unlock the sim programmatically, which is working fine, but I'm having problems hiding the "Enter PIN" screen. I need to hide it because I don't want users to try and guess the pin, thereby blocking the sim card.

[image: Enter PIN Screen]

Comment: Where do you see this screen? I've never encountered this on my Windows Mobile devices.

Comment: Whenever the handheld is rebooted or the gprs radio is turned on or off. http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/4355/pinscreen.jpg